# Compare solutions of counting sort

Tags: sorting

I was looking for implementations of counting sort and most of them are implemented with cumulative counts like this:

```
public void SortArray1(int[] nums)
    {
        var output = new int[nums.Length];

        var count = new int[nums.Max() + 1];
        foreach (var num in nums)
            count[num]++;

        for (int i = 1; i < count.Length; i++)
            count[i] += count[i - 1];

        for (int i = nums.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var index = count[nums[i]] - 1;
            output[index] = nums[i];
            count[nums[i]]--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            nums[i] = output[i];
    }
```

But actually it can be also implemented without cumulative counts:

```
public void SortArray2(int[] nums)
    {
        var count = new int[nums.Max() + 1];
        foreach (var num in nums) 
            count[num]++;

        int number = 0; int index = 0;

        while (index < nums.Length)
        {
            while (count[number]-- > 0)
                nums[index++] = number;
            number++;
        }
    }
```

I am interested what is the reason behind it. Maybe first approach has some advantages and I miss them. Second approach looks better to me and I want to be confident when using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two important advantages of the original counting sort implementation. First, the original version can easily be modified in case the items (keys) being sorted includes additional data. Say you are sorting objects that contains an ID and name, and these objects must be sorted by their ID. The original version does not simply accumulate the count of each key but it moves the actual elements around. However, to do this the algorithm needs an extra array. Hence, it is not an in-place algorithm, which can be disadvantageous sometimes.

The second is that it is guaranteed to be stable (order of items with equal keys is retained). It is not clear to me if your implementation will also be stable since you are not keeping the original elements.